# Objects won't render when camera is parented to an object

Tags: rendering, camera, parent

So I'm trying to make my camera follow a spaceship around, so I've tried parenting it to the rear of the ship. However, doing this causes the game to just display a grey rectangle when playing through the camera view. Unparenting the camera resolves the issue. Has anyone seen anything like this?[image]

[image]

Comment: I use that all the time, there must be something else going on

Comment: Hmm. Parenting the camera to other objects in the scene works fine. There's something about the ship in particular. Parenting an empty to the ship and then the camera to the empty doesn't work either.

Comment: Your .blend would help.

Comment: parent something visible to the camera ( same position ) , start playing not in camera view  and see where it goes ( probably the camera is moving away and has nothing to show )

Comment: my guess is something is getting mussed up with the collision/parent relationship. view from outside the cameras port to see.